# How to get Android Enterprise details related to Gmail account

Tags: android-management-api, android-enterprise, android-enterprise-features

I'm trying to fetch the details of Enterprise related to an Gmail account, is there any default API to fetch the Enterprise details related to Gmail account ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the enterprise details by logging into play.google.com/work with the account that was used to create it.

Click on Admin Settings to see the Organization name and Organization ID

[image]

There's no `API` which will give you the details of the `Enterprise` because all the API requests in *Android Management API* have the `enterpriseId` as the parent key.

Comment: Yes ,we have to display the Enterprise details associated with email id ..

Comment: You can save the email and it's Enterprise Details in DB, which can be displayed to user on a API call or something.